# CMake не может найти SDL_TTF_LIBRARIES и SDL_TTF_DIRS

Tags: c, cmake, sdl2, sdl

Хочу сделать свой SDL2 проект при помощи CMake, однако он не может найти SDL_TTF_LIBRARIES и SDL_TTF_DIRS

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL_ttf (missing: SDL_TTF_LIBRARIES SDL_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL_ttf.cmake:91 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

мой `CMake.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)


project(tetris)

find_package(SDL_ttf REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(tetris game.c main.c)

target_include_directories(tetris PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(tetris PRIVATE ${SDL_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(tetris ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(tetris ${SDL_TTF_LIBRARIES})
message(${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А он не `SDL2_ttf` должен называться?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вроде в Cmake встроен find sdl_ttf, если сделать 2 то будет писать  By not providing "FindSDL2_ttf.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_ttf",
  but CMake did not find one.

Comment: Просто, так же как SDL и SDL2 - разные библиотеки, SDL_ttf и SDL2_ttf тоже разные. Но возможно просто пакет неправильно назван...

Comment: не могу понять что вводить и искать к сожалению

Comment: `FindSDL2_ttf.cmake` в коробке не поставляется: или накидай свой (или сопри из какого-то проекта), или используй pkg-config…

Comment: как это сделать с помощью pkg - config, не подскажете если не сложно?

Comment: @win98_4k_support, как-то так: `find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)` `pkg_check_modules(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)` `target_include_directories(tetris PRIVATE ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})` `target_link_libraries(tetris ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES})` ЗЫ: не забудь установить `-dev` пакет для `sdl2-ttf`… ЗЗЫ: на будущее, если ждёшь ответа на вопрос/просьбу в комментариях, упоминай того, кого спрашиваешь через `@` собаку .

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо огромное)